# Sed to replace a word from another file content

Tags: linux, sed

Hi I am looking some help for sed from gurus ,
basically i git two files

```
First :- serial.txt
second :- info.txt
```

file `serial.txt` has a unique information.
and file `info.txt` has

```
"http://irequestedserver1?u=user:p=123"
"http://irequestedserver2?u=user:p=123"
and more and more
```

I want to replace user word with the info stored in first file serial.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `serial.txt` file contains a name, then you can try something like this:

```
$ cat serial.txt 
jaypal

$ cat info.txt 
"http://irequestedserver1?u=user:p=123"
"http://irequestedserver2?u=user:p=123"

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for (name in a) {sub(/u=.*:/,"u="name":")}}1' serial.txt info.txt 
"http://irequestedserver1?u=jaypal:p=123"
"http://irequestedserver2?u=jaypal:p=123"
```

Comment: Great Works like charm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `serial.txt` contains a single line of information that is to be used for *all* lines in `info.txt`:

```
 sed -r 's/\?u=[^:]+:/\?u='"$(tr -d '\n' < serial.txt)"':/' info.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ,but Its not reading the content from serial.txt , its just delete user and leave it blank.

Comment: @user2901827 Do you get an error message? What is the exact content and format of `serial.txt`? Are there extra leading/trailing newlines? What happens if you `cat` it interactively vs. interactively running `echo "$(<serial.txt)"`? I've updated my answer to remove newlines from `serial.txt` on substitution - see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
var=$(<serial.txt)
sed -r "s/(u=user:)([^\"]*)/\1${var}/" info.txt
```